# Universal word part for ~ in 'you can ~ by it'

Tags: word-choice

We have words like 'visible' and 'audible'.  You can see it or hear it, respectively. But is there a word part for 'you can ~ with it'?  Like: "You can see with this chip.  It's visifying.'

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're asking here. You see with your eyes. I don't understand seeing with a chip. Could you try and explain a little more?

Comment: You remember that movie where the lead man's vision is resorted by a computer chip that's implanted into his skull?

Comment: Do you mean a microchip? Does the chip actually give the man the ability to see? You will have to be more specific.

Comment: I think OP is asking whether there is an affix like *-ble* which expresses "providing the ability to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English does not have any suffix I know of which expresses the sense *providing the ability to* do something.

Ordinarily we would construct such a sense with the verb *enable*, followed by the ordinary English noun which expresses the ability:

> This device enables hearing.
>   This chip enables sight.
>   This method enables speech.

If you require an adjectival form this would be constructed with *NOUN* + - + present participle *OR* past participle of *enable*:

> Wolfpack has just introduced a new sight-enabling chip.
>   Wolfpack has just introduced a new speech-enabled robot.

But that doesn’t work very well with gerunds, due to the *horror aequi* principle which avoids juxtaposing similar forms:

> <sup>?</sup> Wolfpack has just introduced a new hearing-enabling device.

If you really really ***desperately*** require a one-word, Latinate form you might try *-potentiate, -potentiating, -potentiated*:

> Wolfpack's visipotentiating chip will launch a revolution in intelligence gathering.
>   Wolfpack's device audipotentiates sufferers from conductive hearing loss.
>   Wolfpack's new loquipotentiated robot can carry on actual conversations!

But that's really really far-fetched.

Comment: Wow, StoneyB!  This is really informative.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear but let me try.

> *You can see with this chip. It's **visible.*** -what's the problem in this?

Or you want...

> *You can **visualize** with it.* Here, [visualize means](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/visualize?q=visualize) *make something visible to the eye.*

Or...

*Audible* and *Visible* in this context are *adjectives* and you looking for another adjective for the word **see**? If yes, then it's *seeable* or *viewable* -though the former one is not too frequently used.

> [seeable (adj)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SEEABLE) - Capable of being seen; or open to easy view.

Comment: Maulik: Reverse dictionary for "as a means of" or "used for" (i.e., 'as a means of seeing').  Perhaps 'pro' in "pro-vision" or "pro-audio".

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I din' get anything you said!

Comment: Okay.  Basically: `visible: can be seen; visipotentiating/pro-vision: enables vision`.  Visible is like 'in the vision'.  vision-enabling is like 'turns the eyes on'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a word that encompasses either "visible" or "audible", consider "[perceivable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perceivable)":

> Adj....capable of being perceived especially by sight or hearing; "perceivable through the mist"

or "[perceptible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perceptible)":

> adj.
>   Capable of being perceived by the senses or the mind: *perceptible sounds in the night*.

In the context of your phrase, this would read, "You can perceive with it." If you wanted to form a [compound modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier), you could then add, "It's perception-enabling," but it's a little more awkward. I can't think of a non-compound alternative to "visifying", which itself is not commonly accepted as a word.

You could also use "sense" instead of "perceive" here, but I would recommend against using "[sensible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sensible)" for your purposes. Its first definition fits the meaning, but it's somewhat more ambiguous because people often use "sensible" to mean logical or reasonable, more or less. BTW, the technical distinction between sensation and perception (in psychological literature, at least) is between the actions of the sensory organs (e.g., the eyes receiving light) vs. mental processes in conscious experiences (e.g., a person becoming aware of light).